# Do multiple .repeats() do anything to a flux in project reactor?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

What/is there a difference between:

```
flux2 = flux1.repeat().map(x -> x + 1).repeat();
```

and

```
flux2 = flux1.repeat().map(x -> x + 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `Flux` never completes because of the first `repeat()`, the second `repeat()` will never have a chance to resubscribe so it's basically a **no-op**.

However, note that this is not always the case for any two repeats within a `Flux` chain. If between the first and the second repeat there is an operator which would complete the publisher based on some condition (e.g. `take`, `takeUntil`), then the second repeat would make the otherwise finite `Flux` infinite.